# GSM900 module sending/receiving sms limits per minute

Tags: sms, raspberry-pi, gsm, sms-gateway

I want to know the limitations of this GSM module, means how much sms can i maximum send and receive using this module per minute. I am planning to use it along with the RaspberryPi.

Comment: Have you tried doing some tests?  In general, you should not use a modem to send/receive a large volume of SMSs.  The best way to do this is to rent space on an SMS gateway server, that is connected directly to the operator's SMSC in the core network.

Comment: it is SIM900 GSM module.
Yes, @SList you are right,but I dont have bulk-requirement for SMS right now (just few hundreds/ day). And to host a space on SMS gateway server in India, your requirement sholud be high enough otherwise it will be costly.
I have performed the successful test using Netlog Sms-gateway server.
now i want to perform with GSM900,I just wanted to know the Maximum sending/receiving capacity of this module before hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your questioning the GSM 900 module aims at the wrong part of the delivery food chain.

The real imitation is 'always' the carrier accepting the text message. If you expect 1 message per 5 seconds you should never be disappointed and if you try more than 1 message every second you will surely find messages failing. The point at which you experience failure will depend on the buffering/caching setup by the sms gateway / carrier.